# Automatically add divs to product descriptions in Shopify

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm trying to add divs to product descriptions in Shopify so that I can then create an accordion.
Currently my code looks like this

In the .liquid file:

```
<div class="product-single__description rte">
  {{ product.description }}
</div>
```

This is the output:

```
<div class="product-single__description rte">
  <h2>TEXT</h2>
  <h4>TEXT</h4>
  <p><em>Text</em></p>
  <h4>TEXT</h4>
  <p>Text</p>
  <h2>TEXT</h2>
  <h4>Text</h4>
  <p>Text</p>
  <h4>TEXT</h4>
  <p>Text</p>
  <h4>TEXT</h4>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p><em>Text</em></p>
</div>
```

My goal is to insert a div wrapper and enclose the content from H2 to the next h2, so for example:

```
<div class="product-single__description rte">

  <div class=“class_1”
    <h2>TEXT</h2>
    <h4>TEXT</h4>
    <p ><em>Text</em></p>
    <h4>TEXT</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

  <div class=“class_2”
    <h2>TEXT</h2>
    <h4>Text</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
    <h4>TEXT</h4>
    <p >Text</p>
    <h4>TEXT</h4>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p><em>Text</em></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

The number of H2s and the content changes from product to product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are a few checks that you need to make before you do this.

First we will set a variable for the content:

```
{% assign content = product.description %}
```

After that we will check if the if there is a plain `<h2>` in there

```
{% if content contains '<h2>' %}
  // logic to add here
{% else %}
  {{content}}
{% endif %}
```

(have in mind that if your h2 tags have any inline styles you will have to target `<h2` instead)

If there is we will continue the logic inside the `if`, but if there is not we will output the plain content in the `else` statement.

So we are now in the `// logic to add here` part here.

We will split the content by `<h2>` like so:

```
{% assign content_arr = content | split: '<h2>' %}
```

We will check if you have some content before the first `<h2>` since we don't want to loose it in that case, so we check it like so:

```
{% if content_arr[0] != '' %}
  {{content_arr[0]}}
{% endif %}
```

We need to loop the rest of the items of the array.

Since we are splitting by `<h2>` if there is no content before the `<h2>` it will return an empty array for the first item and we don't need that one. So we will offset the for loop by 1 item:

```
{% for item in content_arr offset: 1 %}
  // items here
{% endfor %}
```

Now we need to return the opening `<h2>` tag (since we removed it from the content) and show the rest of the content.

It's easy as writing `<h2>` before the `{{item}}`:

```
<div class="class_{{forloop.index}}">
  <h2>{{item}}
</div>
```

And that's all.

---

Here is the full code:

```
{% assign content = product.description %}

{% if content contains '<h2>' %}
  {% assign content_arr = content | split: '<h2>' %}
  {% if content_arr[0] != '' %}
    {{content_arr[0]}}
  {% endif %}
  {% for item in content_arr offset: 1 %}
    <div class="class_{{forloop.index}}">
      <h2>{{item}}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  {{content}}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You may try this (not tested but it should work):

```
{% assign desc_parts = product.description | split:'<h2>' %}
{% for part in desc_parts offset:1 %}
    <div class="class_{{ forloop.index }}">
        {{ part | prepend:'<h2>' }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Explanations:

- As you do not have clean separator in product description, let's use
  h2 tag.
- Then, you create an array with this separator (split
  function).
- Then you loop through your array, with an offset to 1 to
  avoid the empty first elem (or you may use it later or before to display it in a separated div it there is something before the first h2 tag). To display separately the first elem, use {{ desc_parts.first }}.
- To get a unique class or id, you may
  use the loop index.
- As the h2 tag is the separator used to create
  the array, you need to prepend your elem with it.

Please note that you should also think about the case with a product description without h2 and manage this case in your code.